# How to pass email address to webhook from MailChimp

Tags: php, mailchimp, webhooks

I am building a web app in PHP that subscribes and unsubscribes members from a MailChimp list via the API.

What I'm trying to add (and having extreme difficulty with) is use the MailChimp web hook features to pass the email address of someone that has unsubscribed through MailChimp to the hook that I have created on my app to that it will then update the database.

The app expects to receive the below URL to update the database

```
domain.com/includes/mailchimp-update.php?email=mail@domain.com
```

I am unsure as how to get that from the MailChimp web hook, and cannot find anything on here about it or on MailChimp, and their live help was not that helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is struggling with this, here is how I resolved it.

Using the mailchimp webhook passes an array of data via POST.  To pull the email address from the array, simply use.

```
$email = $_POST ['data']['email'];
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with C# and ASP.NET MVC?